# How to handle bootstrap button without any href in Jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, css-selectors

Im trying to test performance for a web app and I'm currently blocked on a page which has submit button without any hyperlink.

How do I navigate to the next page?

This is the button im trying to use to navigate to the next page: [Next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/micVT.png)

I tried using the CSS selection extractor in Jmeter, its reading the value of the button(I can see in the debug sampler) but without any hyperlink im unable to use that as a *path* for navigating to next page. [Debug Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDdZ7.png)

Comment: Does it need a hyperlink ? Can't you just make it go to localhost ?

Comment: @sln: No, because I've used css selector extractor(read the href) for the previous requests to navigate till here. Now Im stuck on this page as the submit(Next) button is a bootstrap without href. I'm unsure how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter (not webdriver sampler) works on request level and not on gui level. So, you need to capture the request to navigates to the next page and not to click on the button.

Try [jmeter recording.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or directly put the path of the landing page in a new http sampler manually.

Hope this helps.